# Get missing cyclic numbers via modulus?

Tags: equation-solving, modular-arithmetic, coefficients

Consider a list of numbers:

```
list = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Taking a random set of three of these numbers:

```
{n1, n2, n3} = RandomSample[list, 3] // Sort
```

> `{1, 3, 4}`

I would like to determine general coefficients `a1,a2,a3` and `b1,b2,b3`:

```
n4 = Mod[a1 n1 + a2 n2 + a3 n3 , 5, 1] ;
n5 = Mod[b1 n1 + b2 n2 + b3 n3 , 5, 1] ;
```

such that `n4` and `n5` are set to the remaining two numbers, not appearing in `{n1, n2, n3}`, in increasing order. So, for the example above we should have:

```
{n4, n5}
```

> `{2, 5}`

Is there a way to use Mathematica to solve for the unknowns `a1,a2,a3` and `b1,b2,b3`, or determine if no such solution exists? Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: For your example, you could do `FindInstance[{a1 + 3 a2 + 4 a3 == 2, b1 + 3 b2 + 4 b3 == 5}, {a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3}, Modulus -> 5]`

Comment: @CarlWoll Yes, but my problem is that I need a closed form solution. By brute forcing I just noticed that no solution seems to exist in a sensible range of coefficient values. Trying to add more coefficients and higher powers of `ni` now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this specific example with brute force, e.g.:

```
su = Subsets[Range[5], {3}];
tu = Tuples[su, 2];
fun[x_] := 
 Pick[tu, (Mod[#.x, 5, 1] == Complement[Range[5], x] & /@ tu)]
Column[Table[j -> MatrixForm /@ fun[j], {j, su}]]
```

[image]